# Service error Bot should use its own storage

Tags: azure, botframework, dialogflow-es, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I've created bot (Bot Framework v3) which uses LUIS, QnAMaker, Dialogflow services. It works perfectly when I run it locally in the Bot Emulator, but when I deploy it on Azure my bot stops working. On the surface he just replies **Sorry, my bot code has an issue** and in the Settings-Web Chat blade of the application there is a **500 InternalServerError**.

I tried to debug with ngrok, and I got an exception **Operation returned an invalid status code 'MethodNotAllowed'** with Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ErrorResponse  message **Bot should use its own storage** in my MessageController in method `await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog().DefaultIfException());`

Also, the first message that was intended to be sent by the bot which is processed in ConversationUpdate is successfully sent to a user without any error.

I'm using Azure Table Storage, and I've also tried InMemory storage. There is also some work with a local database in my bot.

I also have a web app bot that was created a few months ago, and I tried to deploy this bot and it works fine. So, I suppose maybe I missed something in this new web app bot configurations or there is some other issue I'm not aware of. I've already checked all my app service keys many times.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found a solution. You must be sure that you have these lines of code in your Global.asax file

```
builder.Register(c => store)
       .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
       .AsSelf()
       .SingleInstance();

builder.Register(c => new CachingBotDataStore(store,
         CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy
        .ETagBasedConsistency))
        .As<IBotDataStore<BotData>>()
        .AsSelf()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

and use either Azure Table Storage or CosmosDb.

I just hadn't use CachingBotDataStore and its absence caused the error.